# The light is being reflected inside the bulb.How to fix it?

Tags: rendering, light

I can't seem to find a solution for this problem
[image]
Is there any possible fix without affecting how the glass look like?

File: 
[image]

Comment: Please upload your .blend to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Can you find it now ?

Comment: Yes, if no one else does I'll may have a look at it later, although it seems to me that it is expected but unwanted behaviour

Comment: The only correct solution is to keep the reflection...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement this, you just have to ensure that the light from the filament is not bouncing off or interacting with too many surfaces (in technical terms 'bounces').In our case, if the light from the filament comes through the front of the bulb, it means the emission ray from the filament is converted to transmission ray (at the front portion of bulb) and reaches camera. Which means 2 bounces. But in the case of the additional reflections, the bounces are more.

So all we have to do is, make the rays which have more than 2 bounces invisible. We can get this bounce information from 'Ray depth' of 'Light path' node.

> Ray Depth is the Number of times the ray has “bounced”, i.e. been reflected
>   or transmitted on interaction with a surface.

In material node editor, Shift+A and Input>Light path. Also, we can get the 'greater than' operation from math node. Shift+A, Converter>Math and change the operation in the drop down menu to 'greater than'.

Check out the following node setup for emission material of the filament.You can do the same for the rest of the materials that are getting reflected.

[image]

Comment: That's what i was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this setup, which is very similar to @Teja's but will not restrict the total bounces in the same way. In this scene, the bulb is seen in a mirror.

[image]

This says:'I dont want to hear from the element if its asked by a ray whose transmission depth is greater than 2, or it's being asked for a reflection'

Without the fix:

[image]

With the fix:

[image]

..but it's still not perfect.. if you looked at your bulb through a window, its filament would disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It is Physically Right. Glass always reflect a little bit Reflection, Anyways here's a trick:

Use A Refraction BSDF instead of Glass BSDF.

[image]
Here's the Render:

[image]

**Unrelated:** I checked your Metal Shader, you added diffuse to it. Metal is 100% Gloss

Check: [Blender Guru Tutorial For Metals](https://youtu.be/m1PkSViBi-M?t=199)

Comment: Thank you .I have already tried using the "Refraction BSDF" but its not as good as the glass.

Comment: Results are same I think (except Reflection), Anyway That's the Solution.